# How to calculate area of triangle with perpendicular lines

Tags: algebra-precalculus

1. In the figure below, the lines have slopes of 3 and 5. The lines intersect at (10,15). How far is it between the x-intercepts of the lines?

[image]

The equation of the line with slope of 3 is $y=3x+b$ and with the point $(10,15)$ is $15=3(10)+b$ so the equation is $y=3x-15$

Similarly, the slope is 5. So the equation is $y=5x-35$

The x intercepts are $x=5$ for $y=3x-15$ and $x=7$ for $y=5x-35$. The distance between the two 2. Is this correct?

2. In the figure below, the two lines are perpendicular, and they intersect at $(6,8)$. The y-intercepts of the lines have a sum of zero. Find the area of the shaded region.

[image]

the equations of the lines are $y=mx+b$ and $y=-(\frac{1}{m})x-b$ since the y-intercepts are opposite each other. If I plug the point back in, I have:

$8=6m+b$ and $8=-(\frac{1}{m})(6)-b$

If I set these two equations together, I'd have

$6m+b=-(\frac{1}{m})(6)-b$

$6m=-\frac{6}{m}$

$6m^2 = -6$

$6m^2+6=0$

$6(m^2+1)=0$

Here I am stuck because I have a negative root so I'm pretty sure I attempted this problem wrong.

Comment: The step from $6m+b=-(\frac{1}{m})(6)-b$ to $6m=-\frac{6}{m}$ is incorrect.

Comment: oh right. but then i have an equation in terms of two variables, $m$ and $b$ so I still wouldn't be able to solve it

Comment: Since $b=8-6m$, we have $8=-\frac 6m-(8-6m)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer to the first question is correct.

For the second question, your error, as pointed out in the comment above, was that you accidentally cancelled the $b$'s, even though they had opposite signs. You have two equations:

$$8 = 6m+b \tag{1}$$

$$8 = -\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)6-b \tag{2}$$

There are multiple ways this system can be solved. For instance, you can isolate $b$ in equation $(1)$ and plug it in equation $(2)$.

$$8 = 6m+b \iff \color{blue}{b = 8-6m} \tag{1}$$

$$\implies 8 = -\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)6-\color{blue}{(8-6m)}$$

Can you take it on from here?

Comment: Well I'll solve for m and then I'll have the equations for both lines. Then I can calculate the y-intercept of two intercepts and that would give me the hypotenuse of the triangle. then i can calculate the height from the top y-intercept and the intersection point using the distance formula. then i can calculate the base from the other y-intercept to the intersection point and use the formula for area of a triangle, right?

Comment: Precisely! However, in the general case, we have $A_{\triangle} = \frac{1}{2}ab\sin(C)$, so if we take $C$ to be the right-angle, it all simplifies to half the product of the lengths of the two legs, so the length of the hypotenuse is actually not needed. (Of course, if you also find the length of the hypotenuse, Heron's formula would also work, but it's just extra work really.)

Comment: so when I solve for $m$ I get $m=\frac{16\pm\sqrt{112}}{12}$ is this correct? this seems too complicated for the slope

Comment: No, you get simply $m = 3$ and $m = -\frac{1}{3}$. $$8 = -\frac{6}{m}-8+6m \iff 6m-16-\frac{6}{m} = 0$$ From here, assuming $m \neq 0$, we continue by multiplying both sides by $m$: $$6m^2-16m-6 = 0 \iff 3m^2-8m-3 = 0 \iff 3m^2-9m+m-3 = 0 \iff 3m(m-3)+1(m-3) = 0 \iff (3m+1)(m-3) = 0 \iff \begin{cases} 3m+1 = 0 \iff m = -\frac{1}{3} \\ m-3 = 0 \iff m = 3 \end{cases}$$

Comment: weird. I did $6m^2-16m-6=0$ and used the quadratic formula and got my weird answer but thank you for clarifying.